Offline speech recognition for Russian language for Windows
I have tons on notes made in mp3 files which I want to transcribe into text notes. I don't want to use online tools because of privacy reasons.
Could you please recommend the tool to transcribe them offline (preferably one which could use the power of GPU)?
I am fine to have some ready to use solution or any kind of open-source product which need to be trained for my voice, etc. Even generic voice-to-speech ML Transformer tool/library would work.
I need to use it for Russian language on Windows.
